# Runtime error 429 when creating PowerPoint presentation from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, powerpoint

I am trying to create a new PPT based on an Excel sheet. The macro is located in the Excel file.
I receive

> Run time 429 error: ActiveX component can't create object.

I went through MicroSoft help. Someone also mentioned the reference library so I added the Microsoft Powerpoint Reference to my Library.

Do I need to add an ActiveX Reference as well?

```
Sub PPT()

Dim r As Range
Dim powerpointapp As Object
Dim mypresentation As Object
Dim myslide As Object
Dim myshape As Object

Dim Cell As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet
    
'set worksheets
With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = .Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set wsDestination = .Worksheets("Sheet 1")
End With
LastRow1 = wsDestination.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn1 = wsDestination.Cells(4, wsDestination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(wsDestination.Cells(LastRow1, 1), wsDestination.Cells(LastRow1, LastColumn1)).Select

'assigning range into variable
Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(LastRow1, LastColumn1))

'if we already opened powerpoint
Set powerpointapp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'if powerpoint is not opened
'this is the line that causes the error 
If powerpointapp Is Nothing Then Set powerpointapp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'to create a new presentation
Set mypresentation = powerpointapp.Presentations.Add
Set myslide = mypresentation.slides.Add(1, 11)
r.Copy

'to paste range
myslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
Set myshape = myslide.Shapes(myslide.Shapes.Count)
myshape.Left = 250
myshape.Top = 150
powerpointapp.Visible = True
powerpointapp.Activate

'to clear the cutcopymode from clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a comma when using `GetObject`. You may want to read up on [GetObject and CreateObject behavior of Office automation servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/getobject-createobject-behavior). There will also see how to handle the **trappable Run-time error '429':**

For example

```
Set powerpointapp = GetObject(,"PowerPoint.Application")`
```

Also you need to handle the error if no existing powerpoint instance is found. For example

```
'~~> Establish an PowerPoint application object
On Error Resume Next
'~~> Check if there is already an existing instance
Set powerpointapp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    '~~> If not found then create one
    Set powerpointapp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

Set mypresentation = powerpointapp.Presentations.Add

'~~> Rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code,

For me the same error was thrown on `Set powerpointapp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")`

That happend because there was no powerpoint app created, that's the expected behavior,
To overcome this you can do:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set powerpointapp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
```

On your code you mention that the line with the error is this one:

```
If powerpointapp Is Nothing Then Set powerpointapp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
```

Well this line seems fine, you can change it for:

```
If powerpointapp Is Nothing Then Set powerpointapp = New PowerPoint.Application
```

in this case I still reccomend changing the variable type `Object` to `PowerPoint.Application` you will get intellisense tips